# Weird behaviour with ui-router default state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I cannot explain the behaviour as far as the default state is concerned. My code is the following: 
First **index.html**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div class="container">    
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>

</body>
```

**app.js**:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'partial-home.html'
        })

        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'partial-about.html'       
        });

});
```

**partial-home.html:**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
    <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>    
</div>
```

**partial-about.html:**

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The About Page</h1>
    <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>    
</div>
```

I cannot figure out how ui-router works as to default to a state. From my previous experience with ng-view, I thought that `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');` would decide about the default state. This is the case that index.html always defaults to the last selected state like it is stored session or localStorage.

*And something last*: Is `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');` enough for activating state 'home'? If ommiting it, the initial page should not show neither partial-home.html nor partial-about.html. Isn't it?

Comment: normaly you parametrize all your state with `state(...)` and to call the rigth template when you call your state or his associate address. So in fact otherwise is here just to redirect user to a default state if the browser address is not parametrize.

Comment: @ILIAS $urlRouterProvider decides the default state. If any of the above defined state is not in the URL then it will redirect to the state mentioned inside urlRouterProvider. But this is alone not enough to activate state home

Comment: You have to define home state like other states. urlRouterProvider only execute if none of the defined state is available in the url